# Mock method call and return value without running the method (MockK)

Tags: mocking, mockito, mockk

I saw similar post: [How to mock method call and return value without running the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308877/how-to-mock-method-call-and-return-value-without-running-the-method)

I am wondering if there is similar method we can use in mockK?
something like: doReturn.when(mock).method in mockito

I saw this question before [Equivalent of doReturn(x).when(y)... in mockk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682624/equivalent-of-doreturnx-wheny-in-mockk)

But the answer is: every (method) returns (value)...
which is not what I want. Because every(method) will actually run the method

Answer (score 1):

With “every” not executes the original method if you not wish, “every” invalidate the call to original and returns the data declared for will returned.

Example:

```
every { yourMock.getData() } returns yourData
```

If you want call original method can use:

```
every { yourMock.getData() } answers { callOriginal() }
```